# Creating cron jobs for different services in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, yaml

I am trying to create cron jobs for App Engine in Google Cloud Platform. But unfortunately, whenever I try to deploy a cron job, it is also overwriting the other job. Also, they are present in different directories. Please find the CRON.yaml below

```
cron:
 - description: "sample1"
   url: /
   target: sample1
   schedule: everyday 08:10
   timezone: Asia/Singapore

cron:
 - description: "sample2"
   url: /
   target: sample2
   schedule: everyday 08:00
   timezone: Asia/Singapore
```

Both are different cron.yaml files. But when I deploy using 
`gcloud app deploy --project <<project>> cron.yaml` , it is overwriting.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions

- Use only one file. Indeed, when you upload CRON description, it overrides all the existing. It's not possible to perform an append. Cron is a yaml list, do this

```
cron:
 - description: "sample1"
   url: /
   target: sample1
   schedule: everyday 08:10
   timezone: Asia/Singapore
 - description: "sample2"
   url: /
   target: sample2
   schedule: everyday 08:00
   timezone: Asia/Singapore
```

- Currently, AppEngine feature are extracted to be available for all other Google Cloud product. By the way, Memcache is became MemoryStore and Cron is became Scheduler (Endpoint is under work for being extracting). So, you can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) for performing your cron. You don't have a YAML file to define, you have to set up a new Google Cloud service by GUI or command line. Be careful, retry policies aren't available by GUI, only with CLI

Comment: Wow thanks :) it worked...but looks so strange, that separate yaml file overwrites the other. But combining in one yaml works like a charm